What are the logical X and Z operators of the two qubits of the toric code?
I am familiar with the surface code, which encodes one logical qubit and the logical X and Z operators are horizontal and vertical lines of X and Z physical gates respectively.
However, the toric code encodes two logical qubits. What are the logical $X_1, X_2, Z_1$ and $Z_2$? On Wikipedia, only two logical operators are highlighted but we need two more.

For logical qubits 1 and 2, $X_1$ ($X_2$) is defined as a horizontal (vertical) string of Pauli $X$'s around the torus, and $Z_1$ ($Z_2$) a vertical (horizontal) string of Pauli $Z$'s around the torus, as shown in the figure here.
The Wikipedia page does actually describe how the two logical operators are defined:

The phase of −1
resulting when braiding the anyons shows that these operations do not commute, but rather anticommute. They may therefore be interpreted as logical
$Z$ and
$X$
Pauli operators on one of the stored qubits. The corresponding logical Pauli's on the other qubit correspond to an
$m$ anyon following the blue loop and an
$e$ anyon following the red.

So I suggest reading the Wikipedia page and/or relevant lecture notes (e.g. [1, 2, 3]) for why the logical operators are defined in this way.

That image on Wikipedia just shows the two noncontractible and homologically inequivalent loops on the torus. You then have $X$ and $Z$ logical operators for each.

Not quite correct, they live on different (inequivalent!) lattice sites.

Yes, that's true; my wording was unclear. You have logical Paulis for each loop on the torus but correctly associated to the primal/dual lattice.*
